# Configuration NLog.config file for using on Azure portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, nlog

I've applied ASP.NET core 3.1 in my web application and I've used NLog for logging.

In local host I set the internalLogFile and fileName like this

```
internalLogFile="E:\Archives\Projects\Alpha\Alpha.Web.App\internal_logs\internallog.txt" 
fileName="E:/Archives/Projects/Alpha/Alpha.Web.App/logs/${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
```

in nlog.config file. How can I set the paths for using in Azure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="E:\Archives\Projects\Alpha\Alpha.Web.App\internal_logs\internallog.txt">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="E:/Archives/Projects/Alpha/Alpha.Web.App/logs/${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

nlog.config file is in this path:

> https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/nlog.config

Comment: Don't assign the absolute path. Use relative path "logs\allLogs.csv". Then from Cloud Explorer (VS2019) or Server Explorer (VS2017) you can find that folder in the App Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `${basedir}` and changed values of internalLogFile and fileName to

```
internalLogFile="${basedir}/internal_logs/internallog.txt">
```

and

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
```

Now I access to these files in `bin` folder in my project.